# how to ignore the argument passed to a method being mocked

Tags: scala, mockito

I am testing my `scala` and `play` code using `Mockito`. My code uses a `save` method which takes a `User` argument. I don't care about the value passed to `save`. I tried to code this behaviour as follows

`when(mockUserRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))`

but I get error

`Error:(219, 36) not found: value any
      when(mockUserRepository.save(any())).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))`

What is the way to specify `any` for `scala` code in `mockito`?

In my `build.sbt`. I have downloaded only `mockito-core`. Do I need something else as well?

`"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.24.5" % "test"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.mockito.Matchers`

```
import org.mockito.Mockito._
import org.mockito.Matchers._

val mockUserRepository = mock[call_your_MockUserRepositiry_service] 
    // something like below 
    // val service = mock[Service[Any, Any]] OR
    // val mockService = mock[MyService]

when(mockUserRepository.save(any)) thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
```

Please refer https://www.programcreek.com/scala/org.mockito.Matchers

**Update:**

If `Matchers` are deprecated in `Mockito 2.0` then you can use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers`

`In Java Something like below`

```
class Foo{
    boolean bool(String str, int i, Object obj) {
        return false;
    }
}

Foo mockFoo = mock(Foo.class);
when(mockFoo.bool(anyString(), anyInt(), any(Object.class))).thenReturn(true);
```

`In Scala something like below`

```
def setupService(inputResponse: Future[Unit]): AdminService = {
    val mockConnector = mock[MongoConnector]

    when(mockConnector.putEntry(ArgumentMatchers.any(), ArgumentMatchers.any())(ArgumentMatchers.any()))
      .thenReturn(inputResponse)

    new AdminService(mockConnector)
  }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I have read that ‘Matchers’ are deprecated from ‘Mockito 2.0’. Is there an alternate approach?

Comment: Then you can use `org.mockito.ArgumentMatcher` to mock the behavior for any argument of the given type.

Answer (score 0):

Try `any[User]` instead of `any()`

Comment: similar error `Error:(221, 36) not found: value any
      when(mockUserRepository.save(any[User])).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))`

Comment: to make any[User] work, I had to include `"org.mockito" %"mockito-all"%"1.10.19"%"test"` instead of `"org.mockito" % "mockito-core" % "2.24.5" % "test"` in `buld.sbt` and do `import org.mockito.Matchers.any` in the spec file. I am not sure if this is the right way though

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that to avoid this and many other issues related to Scala-Java interoperability, you should use the Scala version of Mockito ([mockito-scala](https://github.com/mockito/mockito-scala)) with it, after mix-in the trait `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchersSugar` you can write

```
when(mockUserRepository.save(*)).thenReturn(Future(Some(user)))
```

Or if you fancy a more scala-like syntax

```
mockUserRepository.save(*) shouldReturn Future(Some(user))
```

Check the readme to see more examples and scala specific features

Comment: thanks Bruno. trying `mockito-scala` would be in my mind in future. At the moment, I am very new to `unit-testing` and have already spent some time getting my head around `mockito`. I'll like to develop better knowledge of `Mockito` before I move to `mockito-scala`.

Comment: would I be able to mock `objects` if I use `mockito-scala`. I know that is an issue with `mockito` and the solution to that seem to be `powermockito`.

Comment: You wouldn't, it's usually a hint that something's wrong with your design if you need to mock `objects`

Comment: Ok. As far as I know, `package objects` are the way to create global methods in `Scala`. I am wondering how I can mock such methods then. If you don't mind, could you please take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55089128/the-mock-of-my-class-isnt-getting-called

Comment: Yes, but those global functions are usually pure functions for small utilities, if you have something complex enough that need to be mocked for the sake of testing, you should model it as a trait/class and then inject the dependency (either as a constructor param or as an extra param to the function that uses it) so then in test code you can replace it by a mock