# What is the difference between mockito-core and mockito-all

Tags: mockito

difference between mockito-core and mockito-all? What would I not be able to do if I use only `mockito-core` for example?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`mockito-core` only contains mockito classes, while `mockito-all` contain mockito classes as well as some dependencies, one of them being hamcrest.

In fact `mockito-all` is discontinued [according to the mockito website](https://site.mockito.org/)

> “mockito-all” distribution has been discontinued in Mockito 2.*.

The two packages were/are equivalent but if you depend on `mockito-core` you'll need to add a specific dependency on the packages transitively included in `mockito-all` if you require them in your project.

I've personally experienced some issues when depending on a newer version some `hamcrest` matchers while at the same time having a dependency on `mockito-all`.

Comment: Thanks. I included `mockito-all` as I wasn't able to solve an issue related to matchers with `mockito-core`. It seems I shouldn't use `mockito-all`. Could you please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071728/how-to-ignore-the-argument-passed-to-a-method-being-mocked/55071963#55071963

Comment: as mentioned mockito-all shall no longer be used https://github.com/mockito/mockito/issues/153

Comment: mockito-all is (was) a relic of the past (manuall adding dependencies with Ant) and shouldn't be used with Gradle/Maven/whatever with dependency management. It is precisely described here: https://solidsoft.wordpress.com/2012/09/11/beyond-the-mockito-refcard-part-3-mockito-core-vs-mockito-all-in-mavengradle-based-projects/

Answer (score 2):

Recently, I had JUnit tests can't use the right matcher to match the method as we using hamcrest 1.3, the mockito-all includes the classes from hamcrest of version 1.1, as well as objenesis of 1.0.  Changing to use mockito-core, then add objenesis 1.0 as dependency, with already included dependency for hamcrest 1.3 resolves the issue completely.