# The mock of my class isn't getting called

Tags: scala, mockito

I have a `HelperMethod` class.

```
class HelperMethods {
    def getUniqueID(): UUID = {
        UUID.randomUUID()
    }

    def bucketIDFromEmail(email:String): Int =  {

        val bucketID= email(0).toInt
        println("returning id "+bucketID+" for name "+email)
        bucketID
   }
}
```

And an `object` which has an instance of `HelperMethods`

```
package object utilities{
    private val helper = new HelperMethods()
    def getUniqueID(): UUID = helper.getUniqueID()
    def bucketIDFromEmail(email:String): Int = helper.bucketIDFromEmail(email)  
}
```

I wrote a spec to test that my mock works correctly.

```
class UserControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec {

val mockHelperMethods = mock(classOf[HelperMethods])

  when(mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()).thenReturn(UUID.fromString("87ea52b7-0a70-438f-81ff-b69ab9e57210"))
  when(mockHelperMethods.bucketIDFromEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any[String])).thenReturn(1)

  "mocking helper class " should {
    "work" in {
      val bucketId = utilities.bucketIDFromEmail("t@t.com")
      println("user keys are " + userKeys)

      val id: UUID = utilities.getUniqueID()
      println("got id " + userKeys)

      bucketId mustBe 1
      id mustBe UUID.fromString("87ea52b7-0a70-438f-81ff-b69ab9e57210")

    }
  }
}
```

the test fails with reason `116 was not equal to 1`. This corresponds to line 
 `bucketId mustBe 1` in the spec. I can see the print `returning id 116 for name t@t.com`. I shouldn't see it as I am trying to mock this class. I suspect that it could be because the `utilities` object is getting created before the statement `val mockHelperMethods = mock(classOf[HelperMethods])` in the spec.

Question 2- Is there a way to mock `HelperMethods` and make `utilities` use the mocked class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mocked `HelperMethods` but not `utilities`.

> Question 2- Is there a way to mock HelperMethods and make utilities use the mocked class?

It is not possible to mock an `object`.

If you want, you have to extract the behavior in a `trait`.

Here is a solution that would work:

```
package utils

// move the behavior to a trait:
trait UtitilitiesTrait {
  private[utils] def helper = new HelperMethods()

  def getUniqueID(): UUID = helper.getUniqueID()

  def bucketIDFromEmail(email: String): Int = helper.bucketIDFromEmail(email)
}

// provide an object for real use
object Utilities extends UtitilitiesTrait

// override helper for test mock
object TestUtilities extends UtitilitiesTrait {
  private[utils] override def helper = mock(classOf[HelperMethods])
}
```

And here is your test:

```
class UserControllerUnitSpec extends PlaySpec {

   val mockHelperMethods = mock(classOf[HelperMethods])
   object TestUtilities extends UtitilitiesTrait {
     private[utils] override def helper = mockHelperMethods
   }   
   when(mockHelperMethods.getUniqueID()).thenReturn(UUID.fromString("87ea52b7-0a70-438f-81ff-b69ab9e57210"))
      when(mockHelperMethods.bucketIDFromEmail(ArgumentMatchers.any[String])).thenReturn(1)

  "mocking helper class " should {
    "work" in {
      val bucketId = TestUtilities.bucketIDFromEmail("t@t.com")
      println("user keys are " + userKeys)

      val id: UUID = TestUtilities.getUniqueID()
      println("got id " + userKeys)

      bucketId mustBe 1
      id mustBe UUID.fromString("87ea52b7-0a70-438f-81ff-b69ab9e57210")

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. How will I make the test pick TestUtilities instead of Utilities?

Comment: I added the test to my answer - let me know if you need more explanations

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense. there is one limitation though but its because I didn't explain the scenario completely. In my case, there is a  `controller` in spec and that actually calls `utilities.getUniqueID()` (imaging spec calling `controller.handle message` and `handlemessage` calles utilities.getUniqueID`. I suppose I'll need to inject either `Utilities` or `TestUtilities` in it depending on what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The typical pattern that enables mocking objects used internally is to *inject* them, or at least provide a way to inject an alternate.

Since `Utilities` is an object, you can't inject using a constructor.  You could still introduce a setter method.

If you'd like to discourage use of the setter for anything other than unit tests, make it package-private, and you might also prefix the name with "qa":

```
private[utils] def qaSetHelperMethods(qaHelper: HelperMethods): Unit
```